# Product attribute with dynamic options

Tags: magento2, admin, product-attribute

Is it possible to add a select input to a product where the options are dynamic?

I've specified the path like so:

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
        'manufacturer',
        [
            'type' => 'int',
            'backend' => '',
            'frontend' => '',
            'label' => 'Manufacturer',
            'input' => 'select',
            'class' => '',
            'source' => 'Amrita\Catalog\Model\Config\Source\Options',
            'global' => Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => true,
            'user_defined' => false,
            'default' => 0,
            'searchable' => false,
            'filterable' => false,
            'comparable' => false,
            'visible_on_front' => false,
            'used_in_product_listing' => true,
            'unique' => false,
            'apply_to' => ''
        ]
    );
```

In Options.php i've injected the manufacturerCollectionFactory like so

```
 public function __construct(OptionFactory $optionFactory, CollectionFactory $manufacturerCollectionFactory)
    {
        $this->optionFactory = $optionFactory;
        $this->manufacturerCollectionFactory = $manufacturerCollectionFactory;
        //you can use this if you want to prepare options dynamically

    }
```

I've then tried to add the options in a loop after retrieving the manufacturer collection. I need to set the value and the label of the option by getting the id and title of the manufacturer object, but i'm not sure how to do this using OptionFactory. setLabel() setValue() doesn't work, is there anything equivalent?

```
    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        $manufacturers = $this->manufacturerCollectionFactory->create();
        foreach ($manufacturers as $manufacturer) {
            $option = $this->optionFactory->create();     
//            $option->setLabel();
//            $option->setValue();
//            array_push($this->_options, $option);
        }

        return $this->_options;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue as follows,

```
public function getAllOptions()
    {
        $manufacturers = $this->manufacturerCollectionFactory->create();
        foreach ($manufacturers as $manufacturer) {
            $this->_options[] = [
                    'label' => __($manufacturer['title']),
                    'value' => $manufacturer['id'],
                ];
        }

        return $this->_options;
    }
```